# Как подключить android SDK к Unity3d под Linux Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, unity3d, разработка-игр

мне надо установить и подключить андроид sdk к unity 3d под убунтой, но я не знаю как. Я нажимал на window -> preferences -> external files, но когда пытался выбрать  папку с андроид сдк, то папка не выбиралась, а когда пытался выбрать файлы - они были недоступны для выбора. Я не правильно установил, или что? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Укажите источник,  по которому вы провели описанные в вопросе действия.

Comment: Может у папки с android sdk недостаточно прав(чтение/запись/действия), отсюда может и не выбирается. Еще как вариант, sdk скачали не для linux

Comment: Все уже, разобрался. Надо было более старуб версию android tools